# Why is Pugsley portrayed as such a wimp in the Wednesday TV series?

Tags: addams-family, wednesday

In the TV series [*Wednesday*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wednesday_(TV_series)) (2022), Pugsley is beat up by bullies, picked on by Wednesday, and seems to be pretty much normal.

I have previously only seen the cartoon versions of *The Addams Family* and the [90's movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Addams_Family_(1991_film)) with Doc Brown as Uncle Fester, but all of them gave me the feeling that Pugley was probably the type that would scare bullies off with his own propensity for violence.

And if he did get beat up he would just enjoy it, like all the rest of his family. So what happened in Wednesday? Why did they make him such a wimp?

Comment: "*According to the creators, Pugsley is also the target of bullies. But Wednesday comes to his rescue. “She’s allowed to torture him. Nobody else is,” explains Millar. “That’s the difference. She will defend him to the end against bullies or anything else, but she has license to do what she wants. She’s very protective of him in a very Wednesday way.”*" - https://www.cheatsheet.com/entertainment/wednesday-series-showcases-wednesdays-unique-relationship-pugsley-shes-allowed-to-torture-him-nobody-else-is.html/ The goal seems to be to portray her sympathetically.